# Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL (same domain!)

Tags: javascript, jquery, security

From the page `file://localhost/Users/pistacchio/dev/epress/catflow/test_html/index.html` I have the following (coffeescript) code trying to access an iframe:

```
$('#ipad-viewport iframe').bind 'load', () ->
    console.log $(this).contents().find('map')
```

(This translates to the following javascript, but I don't think the issue relies here):

```
(function() {

  $('#ipad-viewport iframe').bind('load', function() {
    return console.log($(this).contents().find('map'));
  });

}).call(this);
```

I wait for the iframe page to be loaded and try to access an element within its body. I get the following error:

```
Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL file://localhost/Users/pistacchio/dev/epress/catflow/test_html/catalogo/catalog/intro.html from frame with URL file://localhost/Users/pistacchio/dev/epress/catflow/test_html/index.html. Domains, protocols and ports must match.
```

Now, since the iframe is defined like this:

```
<iframe src="file://localhost/Users/pistacchio/dev/epress/catflow/test_html/catalogo/catalog/intro.html" width="1024" height="768"></iframe>
```

Aren't both my page and the iframe in the same domain, or `file://localhost`? Why am I experiencing this problem?

Oh, if relevant, I'm testing this with Chrome 18.

Comment: Seems like file:// is not quite the best wrapper/protocoll to test JS/AJAX.

Comment: it is not an ajax request, I'm not running on a server because there's not server-side work to do, so far.

Comment: just always run it in a server, best way to test if it works

Comment: remove the return, do not return something inside the event, maybe this will help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`file:///` URLs are subject to a slightly different javascript security policy to the normal `same origin policy` that applies to hosted content. In order to stop a saved web page from being able to read the entire contents of your disk, different files are seen as different origins. Just fire up a local server and host your content on that; you will fall back to the "standard" policy where origins are defined by domain/ip.

If for some reason you can't run a web server, you may get some mileage out of the 
command line switch: `--allow-file-access-from-files`. I believe this has the affect of making all `file:///` URLs to be defined as belonging to the same origin.

Comment: While this is as close to a definitive answer as I can find, I'm not sure what relevance the '--allow-file-access-from-files' switch has - it is a command line switch for... A particular browser? Java?

Comment: the command-line parameter was for Chrome, in response to the OP saying he was using Chrome 18