# Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL (Locally)

Tags: javascript, html, frames

Hold your flaming for a re-post, as I have not found anything pertinent yet.

I'm working in a series of nested frames that are intended to be burnt to DVD.

At the most relevant level, I have a frameset of two frames that gets pulled into a frame.

The problem I am encountering is that in one of these two frames, we'll call it the 'controlFrame', I need to make a JS call to the 'mediaFrame'.

As it stands I am 'reaching' for it like so:

```
top.mediaFrame.document
```

And am encountering the above mentioned error; `JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL ... from frame with URL ...`

I understand the implications of cross-domain security in frames, and this is completely reasonable. What I fail to understand is why when these files are in fact located in the same directory, and are being referenced relatively, would this error arise?

Explicitly, the error states that `Domains, protocols and ports must match.`, but I am still receiving this error even when that is clearly the case.

Any thoughts would be marvelous.

Comment: Found some pertinent information here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10516197/unsafe-javascript-attempt-to-access-frame-with-url-same-domain?rq=1
But am still t-boned the way I see it. Any suggestions to work around this would be great.

Comment: So, you're using Chrome? That behavior really is a part of Chrome's security policy. In any other browser local file access is not limited. As an argument was an email (HTML) having an iframe, which could has a code, which sends all stored emails to some server... I read it here at SO a while ago, but I couldn't find it now. Only workaround is to run Chrome with that parameter string mentioned behind the link in your comment.

Comment: Awesome, this is the definitive answer I was looking for, and you should post it as so. As per your comment this is specifically a chrome issue, and launching in internet explorer yields functional results ( aside from the fact I was using top instead of parent... irrelevant ). Thanks for your help.

Comment: I'd rather not post my comment as an answer, it would just be a dup (or a stolen answer). Instead I've found the [original article](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5664399/1169519) for you. The email-thing I mentioned can be found at [Chromium Blog](http://blog.chromium.org/2008/12/security-in-depth-local-web-pages.html), though also this link is in the answer linked above. Upvotes to Justin.